# How to calculate the total price after discount

Tags: c

Now the price after discount is shown but I want to calculate the total price after the discount for 5 items at the end. I have used a for loop in this case

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
float price1,disc,total;
int i;
for (i=0;i<5;i++){

printf("\nEnter price of item : "); //to enter price of item
scanf("%f",&price1);
if(price1<50)
{
    disc=(price1*10)/100; 
    total=price1-disc; //price after discount
    printf("$Item after discount is: %.2f\n",total);
}
else if(price1>=50 && price1<200)
{
        disc=(price1*20)/100; //to cal discount
        total=price1-disc; //price after discount
    printf("$Item after discount is: %.2f\n",total);

}
else if(price1>=200 && price1<=500)
{
        disc=(price1*25)/100; //to cal discount
        total=price1-disc; //price after discount
    printf("$Item after discount is: %.2f\n",total);
}
else if(price1>500)
{
        disc=(price1*30)/100; //to cal discount 
        total=price1-disc; //price after discount
    printf("$Item after discount is: %.2f\n",total);
}


}

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfLmj.png)

Comment: Keep a grand total (initialise it to 0). Add the total per item to the grand total at the end of the loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add your output directly in your question. It's only text, no need to show pictures that mainly contain unused space.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an another float variable as `total_price`. And you can add a sum operation (`total_price +=total;`) to last line of the for loop. With this, At the end of each loop, you will have added the value to the total price. And finally, you can print the value after loop is finished.

Here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
float price1,disc,total;
int i;

float total_price=0;

for (i=0;i<5;i++){

printf("\nEnter price of item : "); //to enter price of item
scanf("%f",&price1);
if(price1<50)
{
    disc=(price1*10)/100; 
    total=price1-disc; //price after discount
    printf("$Item after discount is: %.2f\n",total);
    
}
else if(price1>=50 && price1<200)
{
        disc=(price1*20)/100; //to cal discount
        total=price1-disc; //price after discount
    printf("$Item after discount is: %.2f\n",total);

}
else if(price1>=200 && price1<=500)
{
        disc=(price1*25)/100; //to cal discount
        total=price1-disc; //price after discount
    printf("$Item after discount is: %.2f\n",total);
}
else if(price1>500)
{
        disc=(price1*30)/100; //to cal discount 
        total=price1-disc; //price after discount
    printf("$Item after discount is: %.2f\n",total);
}

total_price +=total;

}
printf("Your total price is: %.2f",total_price);

}
```